# rails get app root/base url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

In my app I have a few APIs that under api domain.  Now in one of the API I want to generate a url that pointing to the main domain, say

```
test.com/blabla...
```

I tried to use  **url_for** but seems the default **root_url** or **request.host** is in api domain. Url_for will make it to be

```
api.test.com/blabla..
```

while I want it to be

```
test.com/blabla...
```

Url_for can take a parameter

```
host: ...
```

to set it to be test.com/, the question is how can I get the root/base url (test.com) for host?  **root_url** or **request.host** are all api.test.com.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-domain) you can do `request.domain`

Answer (score 81):

Just so that it's useful to someone else , i came across this today

```
request.base_url
```

gives the full path in local as well as on live .

```
request.domain
```

gives just the domain name so it sometimes kinda breaks the link while redirecting

Comment: I get `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'request' for main:Object` for both of these.

Comment: Make sure you are writing it in the controller and not in the view

Comment: Use `self.request`. The request is not a local variable, it's an instance variable on a controller.

Comment: You can use this in the view. It just has to be in the context of a request. I.e. it won't work in the Rails console or in a mailer or background job, etc.

Comment: Here's the documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Request/Helpers#base_url-instance_method

Comment: In my case I have only a single domain for any server instance, so I think it's safe to assign a global (eg $base_url = request.base_url) in a before_action method in application_controller.rb so I can access it anywhere downstream of any request.  If it's possible that url could change in a single instance, that might be a bad idea.

Comment: @Rockster160 I had the same problem. The reason for that is the `request` object doesn't exist in the rails console (only in the controller). I found that out from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322757/detect-base-url-in-controller/64323361#comment113743372_64323361) comment

Answer (score 21):

**Simplest alternative method:**

include in you're class

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

create function or just use `root_url` to get app root/base url:

```
  def add_host_prefix(url)
    URI.join(root_url, url).to_s
  end
```

finally: add

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

in:

`Your_project_root_deir/config/environments/development.rb`

although helpers can be accessible only in views but this is working solution.

Comment: Most of this answer doesn't make sense, but I did find the `URI.join('www.newdomain.com', route_path)` concept helpful.

Comment: This has some usefulness for those situations where you don't have a request object to work with. The big downside here is that `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` is beastly expensive.

Answer (score 0):

request.domain fails on CF it given domain url not base url