# Rails for dev, beta, staging and production, get the proper domain name out from api subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321687/rails-get-app-root-base-url), I wanted to get the base url from api subdomain, eg.

```
api.test.com
```

this can be done by

```
request.domain
```

However, if I have different environment as subdomain, say

```
api.dev.test.com,  api.beta.test.com, api.staging.test.com...
```

then request.domain will give me

```
test.com
```

instead of

```
dev.test.com, beta.test.com....etc.
```

Any solution to get the proper domain? root_url, request.host, request.referer won't work in this case. Should I check the environment and set the domain/host in some configuration file when loading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the Rails doc....

```
domain(tld_length = @@tld_length)
```

Returns the domain part of a host, such as “rubyonrails.org” in “www.rubyonrails.org”. You can specify a different tld_length, such as 2 to catch rubyonrails.co.uk in “www.rubyonrails.co.uk”.